# Why is there a gap between images?

Tags: html, css

This is a very simple example. It displays a gap between all 4 images. Doesn't matter if they are in the same div or not.

```
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/GyZpzP)

[image]

Where are these gaps coming from and how do I get rid of them?

I have tested in Chrome, Opera, Firefox and  Safari.

Comment: Have you tried using Crome's debugger tools to inspect?

Comment: Did you try like `margin: -2px;` ?

Comment: @MohammadUsman this it may be a duplicate, but here are other answers that fit better the question.

Comment: can you try out opt that is working for me

Comment: add css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0;
}

Comment: If you were helped by any answer please mark that as the answer so others can follow.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the inline-elements (`<img>`). You can do multiple things. One would be to set `font-size` on the image container to 0.

```css
div.img {
  clear:both;
  font-size:0;
}
div.img img {
  display:inline;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

Another solution using flexbox (more recommended):

```css
div.img {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:start;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

And one more solution with CSS grid:

```css
div.img {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `display: flex` for this to the parent div like below

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Updated*

**Just put `float: left` to the `<img>` and the problem is solved**

The `img` is a block element that's why the gap between them if use `float` to the `img` then it will solve your issue.

To break the images as per the image just add `clear: both;` to the

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}
img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Jithinraj7/pen/EoKKyM)

*Hope this is helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

make use of "`style=float:left`" and `style="line-height:0px;"` will resolve issue . try below it resolve issue of bottom an side space too

```
<div style="line-height:0px;">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" style="float:left;">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div >
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" style="float:left;">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
```

Comment: this will solve just the horizontal gap

Comment: @Edwin - try now problem resolved for both

Comment: @VXp - slashes , not getting you ...

Comment: Ending / closing shasles ( / ). No element needs them.

Comment: @VXp - closing of element needed ...every element has closing tage and some them close with in the declaration only ...but closing is needed thing

Comment: It's not necessary with the HTML5, and also with others before, but not all.